# How to get data from ActiveAndroid to support ListView virtualization

Tags: android, listview, activeandroid

As far as I know, Android listview shows the data virtualized (meaning it loads only the visible ones), so it is fast as it can be.

I have lots of data to get from the database (around 2000 but with lots of data in the fields), and I use ActiveAndroid in an AsyncTask to get them.

Unfortunately the AsyncTask with AA takes around 10-15 seconds to get the data so I see a progressbar during that time.

I get his by this code:

```
  LocalDateTime start=new LocalDateTime();
  LogCat("Start: "+start);
     elements = new Select().from(Data.class)
        .where("Data_Id=?", DataId).orderBy("Name ASC").execute();

  LogCat("Elements: "+elements .size());
  LocalDateTime end=new LocalDateTime();
  LogCat("End: "+end);
  LogCat("Time: "+(new Period(start,end).getSeconds()+" s"));
```

It would be good to accelerate the loading by somehow virtualizing the data retrieval.

I also use a search in the listview, that searches the whole list. So considering the would be also good.

What do you suggest? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Pairing [content provider](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Using-the-content-provider) and [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) should solve your issue.

Comment: I've never done this, I'll give it a try. Will it be effective, what do you reckon?

Comment: I've been using Content Provider and cursor loader in all my apps for some time now and it handles pretty well a large data set. It's also pretty easy to filter.

Comment: That sounds promising. Any chance that you can provide a sample of that? I've never done this, so some guidance would be very helpful.